# Adding items to the list in the list

Tags: python, list, while-loop

I have created a code for the exercise that deals 5 cards to 5 players.
The cards are to be dealt to the list in the "players" list.
I created a while loop in a while loop. This is where my problem comes in: each loop is only performed once and each player is dealt only one card. What is wrong?

```
import random

amountCards = 5

def dealCards(playerCards):
    try:
        len(cards) > 0
        playerCards.append(cards.pop())
    except:
        return False
        
cards = ["9", "9", "9", "9",
            "10", "10", "10", "10",
            "Jack", "Jack", "Jack", "Jack",
            "Queen", "Queen", "Queen", "Queen",
            "King", "King", "King", "King",
            "Ace", "Ace", "Ace", "Ace",
            "Joker", "Joker"]
players = [
            [],
            [],
            [],
            [],
            [],

            ]

random.shuffle(cards)
i=0
a=0

while (i < amountCards):
    while (a < 5):
        dealCards(players[a])
        a+=1
    i+=1


if  len(players) == amountCards:
    for x in players:
        print(*x, sep=", ")
else:
    print ("There were not enough cards for the players")
```

Earlier I solved this problem with just one while loop and calling a function for each list in the list "players".

```
i=0
 
while (i < iloscKart):
    dealCards(players[0])
    dealCards(players[1])
    dealCards(players[2])
    dealCards(players[3])
    dealCards(players[4])
    i+=1
```

But I guess that it  can be shorten this code.
Thanks for the tips

Comment: Replace your `while` loops with `for` loops; they do the index management for you.  You failed to re-initialize `a` on each iteration of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second while loop only runs once because once it reaches 5, it needs to be reset back to zero.

Try this:

```
while (i < amountCards):
    a = 0
    while (a < 5):
        dealCards(players[a])
        a+=1
    i+=1
```